# Find the sum of the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}$

Tags: summation

Find the sum of the

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}$$

**Edit** after YiFan answer

If we take $a_n=1$ , we get:

$$f(x)=\int\frac{1}{x}  \cdot \frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$f(x)=\ln\frac{1}{|x-1|}$$
$$f(\frac{1}{2})= \ln{2}$$

what is equal to wolfram answer

Thank you for the help :).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The summand for $n=0$ is not defined

Comment: Do you mean $\large{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}}?$

Comment: Hint: Taylor series of $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiating geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437287/differentiating-geometric-series)

Comment: Yes i mean n=1. My mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n},$$ then we want to find $f(1/2)$. Make the following two obervations: first that $$\int\frac1x\sum a_nx^n\,dx=\sum\int a_nx^{n-1}\,dx=\sum\frac{a_n}{n}x^{n}$$
so long as exchanging $\int$ and $\sum$ is justified (ask yourself: when is this true?) and then that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer/