# Find a formula for $\sum_{0}^{n}(2i+1)3^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I'm doing "How to prove it" book problems, and I got stuck at this one question that is requesting a formula for the sum $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2i+1)3^i$$ and then to prove it. The proving part is fine but I don't seem to be able to find a formula for the sum, can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric series? In particular, have you seen the proof of the equality $\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^k$ for $|x| < 1$?

Comment: Not yet, I’m still fairly new to pure mathematics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiating geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437287/differentiating-geometric-series)

Comment: If you want to "[peak at the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence)"...

Answer (score 2):

Curious. How do you prove it if you don't know what the formula is yet?

Anyway, some *general* hints (I suspect this problem has a quick, sneaky solution, but I haven't thought of it yet). All mentions of "$x$" shall be to an unspecified real number.

To evaluate something like: $$\sum_{i=0}^n a^i$$You should consider the value of: $$(1-a)\sum_{i=0}^n a^i$$*Expand it with pen and paper for small $n$ if you're unsure.*

Now consider the function $x\mapsto6\sum_{i=0}^nx^i$. From the first part, you know how to calculate this! If you differentiate it with respect to $x$, and evaluate it at $3$, what happens?

Combine now the first and second parts to prove (after some algebra!):

> $$\sum_{i=0}^n(2i+1)3^i=n\cdot3^{n+1}+1$$

A specific strategy: write: $$\sum_{i=0}^n[3^i+i(3^{i+1}-3^i)]=\sum_{i=0}^n3^i+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(j-1)3^j-\sum_{j=0}^nj\cdot3^j\\=\sum_{i=0}^n3^i+(n+1)3^{n+1}-0-\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}3^j=\,?$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2i+1)3^{i}&=2\sum_{i=0}^{n}i3^{i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n}3^{i}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=k}^{n}3^{i}+\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3^{n+1}-3^{k}}{3-1}+\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}3^{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}3^{k}+\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\\
&=n3^{n+1}-\frac{3^{n+1}-3}{2}+\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\\
&=n3^{n+1}+1\\
\end{align}$

Trick is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i3^{i}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=k}^{n}3^{i}$ which we see by writing the numbers in a half square triangular array.